# Printing a list of all the photos in iPhone

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of all the photos in the iPhone camera role. I was using os to list the files but I run into this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Submit Homework\tst.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.listdir(r"This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'This PC\\Apple iPhone\\Internal Storage'
```

Does anyone know the path I need to access the photos in my iPhone

Comment: You need to access it using the drive letter assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The "This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage" path you see in the File Explorer is not a real file on disk that you'd be able to manage with regular file calls in Python (or any other programming language for that matter); to the best of my knowledge it's implemented as an [Explorer Namespace Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works).

You will probably need some other module or library to be able to access the iPhone camera roll.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to what library will do this